# Unable to connect with local MySql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, ubuntu-18.04

I had MySql installed on my local Ubuntu 18.04 machine,
I used the following commands to install it-

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Also installed MySQL Workbench version 6.3 to interact with mysql.

I had 1 local DB and multiple remote connection setup and working till yesterday, Now I am unable to connect with any of the connections.
The dashboard shows a lot of load,
No change in username and password, also tried restarting the system,
 **I am not sure how to resolve it, Following are the screenshots of errors -**
1.
[image]
2.
[image]
3.
[image]
4.
[image]
5.
[image]

**Can someone please help, I've lost all of my data?**

Comment: You never set or create a new connection. that's why its all  became n/a

Comment: I have 1 local and multiple remote connections saved, none of them are connecting. :'(

Comment: did you try to test your connection before proceeding? giving the right port assigned... any

Comment: yes it was all working fine till yesterday, today nothing is opening up.

Comment: did you try a system - reboot ? - did you change any mysql config files ?

Comment: no change in username and password, yes tried re starting the system, the mysql service is not starting for some reason

Comment: Did you check the MySQL error logs?

Comment: I think my MYSQL service had a problem.